# Input type="number" spinners not showing with bootstrap 1.4

Tags: html, webkit, twitter-bootstrap, css-transforms

I've run into a problem where the up/down spinners are not showing in my `<input type="number"/>` elements when using bootstrap 1.4. The spinners are still there: you can click them to increase/decrease the number, even though they're not visible.

I think I've narrowed it down to the following CSS declaration. See http://jsfiddle.net/tKTRx/1/.

```
input, textarea {
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  …
}
```

What does this styling do? Is there a way I can work around it? (It doesn't seem to be a problem in later versions of bootstrap, but I can't upgrade quite yet).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a webkit bug that has been fixed in Chrome Canary. You can read more about the issue on the bootstrap github page: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/630 but the way to fix it is to add a style:

```
input.flat, textarea.flat {
  -webkit-transform-style: flat !important;
}
```

and then when you have a input/textarea add the class `flat`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for that property, assuming you're not actually doing any 3D transforms, is to get the browser to use hardware accelerated rendering for CSS transitions, transforms and animations.  If you're not doing any 3D transforms then it's safe to remove, it may impact performance of 2D transforms on iOS devices.